# In R, how to add additional axises when plotting multiple 3D surface in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, axis

Just like the example data: https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/

I want to make each surface has its own axises, and still be in the same plot.

I have ps the plot that example generates to show what I mean, the upper one is what I have, the bottom one is what I want:

this is what I got:
[image]

this is what I want:
[image]

Can someone tell me how to do it?